# how to use SELECT CASE in sql statment with MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the next sql statment, I want to check value of xxx:

if xxx=1 then "good1"

if xxx=2 then "good2"

if xxx=3 then "good3"

if xxx=4 then "good4"

if xxx=5 then "good5"

```
SELECT
xRef, xPar, AccID, AccLevel, AccType, LEFT(AccCode,1) AS xxx

FROM (
SELECT Parent_AccRef AS xRef, Parent_ParentID AS xPar FROM tblaccountsparents
union ALL
SELECT AccRef AS xRef, AccID AS xPar FROM tblaccounts WHERE AccType<>'final' AND AccParent<>0) xtbl
INNER JOIN tblaccounts ON tblaccounts.AccRef = xtbl.xRef
```

how to use the select case here, I saw many solutions here but not correct for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SELECT
       xRef, xPar, AccID, AccLevel, AccType, LEFT(AccCode,1) AS xxx,
    CASE
       WHEN LEFT(AccCode,1)='1' THEN 'GOOD1'
       WHEN LEFT(AccCode,1)='2' THEN 'GOOD2'
       WHEN LEFT(AccCode,1)='3' THEN 'GOOD3'
       WHEN LEFT(AccCode,1)='4' THEN 'GOOD4'
       ELSE 'SOMETHING ELSE'
   END AS FLAG 

   FROM (
               SELECT Parent_AccRef AS xRef, Parent_ParentID AS xPar FROM            tblaccountsparents
             union ALL
       SELECT AccRef AS xRef, AccID AS xPar FROM tblaccounts WHERE  AccType<>'final'      AND AccParent<>0
        ) xtbl
     INNER JOIN tblaccounts ON tblaccounts.AccRef = xtbl.xRef
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value always 1-5, then how about just creating the string you want using `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT xRef, xPar, AccID, AccLevel, AccType,
       CONCAT('good', LEFT(AccCode,1)) AS whatever
```

If the value can be something else, then you can add a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT xRef, xPar, AccID, AccLevel, AccType,
       (CASE WHEN LEFT(AccCode, 1) BETWEEN '1' AND '5'
             THEN LEFT(CONCAT('good', LEFT(AccCode, 1)) 
        END) AS whatever
```